# angular 2 form elements as components - validation doesnt work

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-directives

i implemented this solution to my project http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/
basicly you build a component with form element and put it into form, the problem i have is that when i want to build a validator that check dependency between fields

```
import {Directive, Attribute} from '@angular/core';

    import {
      NG_VALIDATORS,
      AbstractControl,
    } from '@angular/forms';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[validateEqual][ngModel]',
      providers: [
        {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ParentFieldNotNullValidator, multi: true}
      ]
    })
    export class ParentFieldNotNullValidator {
      constructor(@Attribute('validateEqual') public validateEqual: string) {
      }

      validate(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
        if (!c.value) {
           return null;
        }
        let e = c.root.get(this.validateEqual);

        if (e && e.value) {
          console.log('ERROR 1');
          return null;
        }
        console.log('error 2');
        return {validateError: "message"} }}
```

in regular template driven form its works but in this implementation it doesnt, and i get this kind of stream
[screenshot from webbrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLzL7.png)

this validator should write only 'ERROR 1' when parent field exist and is not null

what i do wrong?
my html:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="u-space-bottom-8">
    <form-input
      cannotContainSpace
      minlength="4"
      required
      name="username"
      [(ngModel)]="user.username">
      >
    </form-input>
  </div>
  <div class="u-space-bottom-8">
    <form-input
      validateEqual="username"
      type="password"
      required
      name="password"
      [(ngModel)]="user.password">
      >
    </form-input>
  </div>
  <button
    class="c-btn c-btn--default u-h-10 u-bg-gray-16 u-paint-white-1"
    type="send"
    [disabled]="!form.valid"
  >
    {{'btn_login'|translate}}
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What, exactly, does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: its very strange behaviour
when i changed this part:
`if (e && e.value)` to this `if (e.value)`

i get an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null**
so my conclustion is that sometimes parent field exist and sometimes not :/ but why?

Comment: I have the same error. I believe it is because c.root for some reason is a reference to c itself, which obviously does not have a child element with identifier "username". I am going to use your solution, but I hope that someone will discover what is going wrong here in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution , problem was with data binding, now my validator looks like this:

```
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  AbstractControl,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validateEqual][ngModel]',
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ParentFieldNotNullValidator, multi: true}
  ]
})
export class ParentFieldNotNullValidator {
  constructor() {
  }
  @Input('validateEqual') parentValue: string;
  validate(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    if (!c.value) {
      return null;
    }
    if (this.parentValue) {
      return null;
    }
    return {parentFieldNotNull: "message"}
  }
}
```

and html look like this

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="u-space-bottom-8">
    <form-input
      cannotContainSpace
      minlength="4"
      required
      name="username"
      [(ngModel)]="user.username">
      >
    </form-input>
  </div>
  <div class="u-space-bottom-8">
    <form-input
      [validateEqual]="user.username"
      type="password"
      required
      name="password"
      [(ngModel)]="user.password">
      >
    </form-input>
  </div>
  <button
    class="c-btn c-btn--default u-h-10 u-bg-gray-16 u-paint-white-1"
    type="wyslij"
    [disabled]="!form.valid"
  >
    {{'btn_login'|translate}}
  </button>
</form>
```